# Zoom conditions on Leaflet weather map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm a new user in Leaflet and I create a weather map with a lot of weathers symbols around the world. 
I can already filter the number of symbols on the map with a function :

```
var filteredSites = filterSitesBySpacing(sites, 0.8);
```

But I would like to filter according to the level zoom. So, I use if condition :

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() <10){
  var filteredSites = filterSitesBySpacing(sites, 0.8);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() >= 10){
  var filteredSites = filterSitesBySpacing(sites, 0.8);
    }  
 }
```

But, it doesn't work...
Could you explain me what is the error in my "if" condition ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained what's not working, but two things to check 1) you are declaring the variable `filteredSites` multiple times; and 2) you are not changing any of the arguments to `fileterdSitesBySpacing` at different zoom levels

Try:

```
var filteredSites; 
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    if (map.getZoom() < 10){
        filteredSites = filterSitesBySpacing(sites, 0.8);
    }
    if (map.getZoom() >= 10){
        // but wait! This will produce exactly the same result as zoom < 10 
        filteredSites = filterSitesBySpacing(sites, 0.8);
    }  
}

console.log(filteredSites);
```

alternatively, use a ternary:

```
var filteredSites;
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    // just guessing some different args for low zoom and high zoom
    var lo_zoom = 0.8;
    var hi_zoom = 80000;

    filteredSites = map.getZoom() < 10 ? filterSitesBySpacing(sites, lo_zoom : filterSitesBySpacing(sites, hi_zoom); 
}

console.log(filteredSites);
```